# Can someone help me grasp the concept of ma (間)?

Tags: meaning

I really need help grasping the concept of 'ma' (間).

I know that this is essentially negative space, or the interval in between, the pause, etc. I can see how this might be seen in art, i.e. Miyazaki's films, but was wondering if anyone else can give me a few concrete examples? I need to explain it to a large group of English speakers, and I know they might not grasp it easily. I want to flesh out my understanding of the concept in order to do so.

Thanks for the help!

Brock

Comment: 間 in Japanese is a fairly mundane word meaning "space", "interval", "pause", "timing", etc., but I doubt any of these concepts are unique to the Japanese language. In what context do you have to explain this word? Why do you think 間 is such a mysterious word?

Comment: To me,  間(ま) as I think it is being (or failing to be) conceived of by OP is one of those slippery and possibly very Japanese notions I'd be hard-put to explain in any adequate manner. (All I can bring myself to say is that  間(ま) in this sense is a kind of device that can be used to or for some effect.) People use the term in commentaries on a variety of things, from oration, music, sports, martial arts, performance and visual arts to literature and manga and anime, probably with slightly different shades of meaning in different contexts.

Comment: Here are a [brief account](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%96%93(%E3%81%BE)-1594491), [blog post](http://rakurakulivenet.com/ra/ra_blog/post-470/) and [study](http://repository.aichi-edu.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/10424/2198/1/kengei4818.pdf) on it (all in Japanese though).

Comment: This question is interesting but not really about language. As Naruto says, the word itself just means "space" or "gap." The rest is cultural overloading.

Answer (score 4):

間 is a word which a native Japanese speaker uses or hears almost every day. Usually it just means "time", "interval", "space", "room", etc. For example:

> - 締め切りまで**間**がある。 There is some more *time* left till the deadline.
> - **間**もなく東京です。　Arriving at Tokyo Station *soon* (lit. "in no time")
> - 行と行の**間**をあける to leave *spaces* between lines, to double-space

Unsurprisingly, such a basic word has dozens of idiomatic expressions which might make little sense if you translated it too literally:

> - 間が悪い (lit. "time is bad") to be done at the wrong time
> - 間に合う (lit. "match the time") to make something on time
> - 間男 (lit. "in-between man") paramour, secret (male) lover

But these may not be of particular interest to native English speakers who don't want to learn Japanese.

So 間 is not really a cool or special word to native Japanese speakers. I'm sometimes surprised to see mundane Japanese words are introduced to foreign countries as something mysterious and cool. For example, see: [What is the exact meaning of "kaizen"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18529/5010)

---

That said, I am vaguely aware that some people have found the concept of 間 as unique to Japan. I found this long article in English: [MA: Place, Space, Void](http://www.kyotojournal.org/the-journal/culture-arts/ma-place-space-void/). The article also explains how 間 is important in certain fields of Japanese art. Honestly speaking, I'm not totally convinced that 間 is such a difficult word, but I think the linked article covers almost everything that you might need.